# Conductor in a capacitor: is there a force attracting the conductor in the capacitor?

Tags: electrostatics

Suppose we have a plane capacitor with dimension LxL, distance d, charge Q. Suppose now to insert a piece of conductor with dimension with same area and thickness d' < d, if one calculate the potential energy of the system it sees that it's going to decrease and so I thought that when I am trying to insert the piece of metal, it will be attracted inside the capacitor so the electrostatic forces are doing positive work in the direction where I'm inserting the conductor. The thing I can't figure out is how can I phyisically explain what's happening inside the conductor, and why this implies a decrease of potential energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the capacitor and the conductor as the system under consideration.

As a conductor comes close enough to feel the effect of the electric field produced by the capacitor charges are induced on the surface of the conductor with positive / negative induced changes closer to the negative / positive changes on the capacitor plate.

So there is a force of attraction between the conductor and the capacitor which can do work, ie pull something and increase its kinetic energy and possibly also increase the kinetic energy of the conductor itself.
Thus the kinetic energy increases whilst the electric potential energy of the system decreases.

Before the conductor entered the capacitor the capacitance of the conductor was $C_{\rm initial}=\frac{\epsilon_0L^2}{d}$ and after the capacitor was fully inside the capacitor the capacitance of the capacitor was $C_{\rm final} =\frac{\epsilon_0L^2}{d-d'}$, thus $C_{\rm final} > C_{\rm initial}$.

As the charge $Q$ is constant the energy stored is $\frac 12 \frac {Q^2}{C}$ the initial electric potential energy is greater than the final electric potential energy.

If the conductor was not pulling anything it would still be attracted into the capacitor, accelerate and its kinetic energy would increase at the expense of a decrease in electric potential energy stored in the system.

After passing a position where the conductor was fully inside the capacitor the conductor would start to slow down due the attractive forces between the induced charges on the conductor and the charges on the plates of the capacitor and so the kinetic energy of the conductor would decrease whilst the electric potential energy of the system would increase.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to compute the Poynting vector of the system in both cases, where you might see how the stored energy flows.

In a capacitor the Poynting vector is static pointing to the axis, as storing Potential Energy:

[image]

And after, when you add the conductor, the capacitor passes to be a simple wire, with charge excess as initial conditions, which are going to go into a normal wire distribution with time, so their Poynting vector will be now of energy transfer from the source to the resistance:

[image]

Concretely if you do the math, when you add the conductor and the capacitor start to discharge, you can see how the Poynting vectors which are pointing into the axis start to rotate until they point to transfer the energy out of the capacitator.

The stored energy in electric circuits theme has been pretty discussed these days since the Veritasium video, I'll link some of those videos if you wanna check how to visualize energy on those systems, also check [Feynman lectures (hyperlink)](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_27.html) on energy stored in a Capacitator.

But summarizing, you should think that what really contains the energy in the systems are the fields it selfs, not really the inside electrons moving etc, which also contribute of course. So you mechanically change the medium, making that electrons can flow, which starts moving the stored energy in the electric/magnetic fields.

**Mentioned videos:**

[Energy doesn't actually flow inside wires](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHIhgxav9LY&t=8s)

[How electricity actually works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oI_X2cMHNe0)